# Macro to calculate maximum number in C++ produces incorrect results

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Variable c is assigned negative one. I can't understand why this code is producing incorrect results as there are parentheses around the macro arguments. Is this a bug or is it a new feature? Using vs2013.

```
#define max(a,b)            (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))

char *buf = "";

int c = max(1024, strlen(buf) - 1);
```

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: I get -1 as the result.

Comment: Try converting max() to a function. If it works, the problem is in using the macro, otherwise it's in the code itself, even if I can't see it.

Comment: Ah, the fun of mixing signed and unsigned expressions.

Comment: `size_t` is unsigned, so maybe it's doing an unsigned comparison between 1024 and 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: `strlen(buf)` returns an `unsigned int` value.

Comment: @Michael can a cast be enough? For example, (signed int)max(1024, strlen(buf) -1)

Comment: @TeoZec: The cast should be applied on `strlen`, otherwise it's worthless.

Answer (score 2):

`std::strlen` returns its value as a `std::size_t`, an implementation-defined unsigned type.

To subtract `strlen(buf)` (`std::size_t`) and `1` (`int`), they need to be converted to a common type.  How that happens [depends on the rank of the two types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), but apparently on your system, both end up converted to `unsigned int`.

And in `unsigned int` arithmetic, `0 - 1` is `MAX_UINT`.

`max(1024, MAX_UINT)` correctly evaluates as `MAX_UINT`.

Then that gets implicitly converted back to `int`, becoming the value `-1`.

Comment: The code has been shipped. My customers are going to be so upset.

Answer (score 1):

Use `(signed)strlen(buf)-1`, and it will yield the expected result.

As a side note, `max(1024, strlen(buf)-1)` generates two calls to function `strlen`, so you might want to store the result of `strlen(buf)-1` in a **`signed`** variable before passing it to the `max` macro.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `strlen` returns a size_t which is unsigned. Since `strlen("") == 0`, `0 - 1` wraps around to 0xFFFFFFFF, which is much larger than 1024. When `c` gets converted to signed int, the result is -1. Try `int c = max(1024, (int)strlen(buf) - 1);`